# Importing a csv into sql using python using mac

Tags: python, sql

I cant seem to get this code to work. It is a relatively small csv file. The terminal responds with an error stating there is an issue with the sql syntax. I think one issue may be macs default use of numbers. I would just like to load this file into sql with two columns and all of the respective data. The database and table has already been created in SQL.

```
import pymysql 
import csv
import time

with open('code1.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='', port=, user='', passwd='', db='', autocommit=True) 
    cur = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

    line = 0
    for row in reader:
        if line == 0:
            line +=1
        else:
            sql = "INSERT INTO name_project('Code', 'Definition')VALUES(%s,%s);"
            cur.execute(sql, (row[0], (str(row[1]))))
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: `cur.execute("INSERT INTO name_project VALUES (%s, %s)", (row[0], str(row[1])))`, possibly with `%s` actually being `'%s'`, enclosed in quotes (I don't use mysql)

Comment: Why do you have single quotes around column names, making them strings, not identifiers? Wouldn't be surprised if that causes an error.

Comment: Also, it would be useful if you put the complete error code instead of describing the error vaguely

Comment: Which dialect and version of SQL are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it this way, there are 1 or 2 syntax errors:

1. Missing a empty space before 'VALUES'
2. Unless your are using dialect such as Postgres, `'Code',
   'Definition' may ought to be`[Code], [Definition]`or just plain`
   Code, Definition`

Additionally, you may want to consider using `pandas` to read the whole csv file as a `DataFrame` using [`.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), then write to your db with [`.to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html).

Comment: Thank you very much, this fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

First off, general advice in such situations is to check what the query that you're passing is, i.e. print the query, check whether it's syntax matches an sql query(you'd be surprised how much we overlook things).

Next run this sql query in the relevant sql server, this might also help in filtering your errors. Later look for syntactical errors.